# issue in panel when using with ajax modal popup control

Tags: asp.net, ajax, modalpopupextender

I have 2 panels and using ajax modalpopup control

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlHead" runat="server"  CssClass="modalPopup">
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlBody" runat="server">
        <div id="popupHead">
            <div id="popup_left">
                <asp:Label ID="lblProduct" runat="server"></asp:Label></div>
            <!-- end banner_left -->
            <div id="popup_right">
            </div>
            <!-- end banner_right -->
        </div>
    </asp:Panel>
    <p>
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="phcontrol" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
    </p>
    <div>
        <center>
            <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnOk" runat="server" OnClick="imgbtnOk_Click" />
        </center>
    </div>
</asp:Panel>

<asp:Panel ID="pnlHeadWD" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopupWD" 
    BackImageUrl="~/WebSiteContent/Images/Cloud.JPG">
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlBodyWD" runat="server">
        <div id="Div1" style="position: absolute; left: 15%; top: 15%; vertical-align: middle;">
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <p>
                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="phcontrolWD" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
            </p>
            <div>
                <center>
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnOkWD" runat="server" Visible="false" OnClientClick="$find('pnlHeadWD').hide(); return false;" />
                </center>
            </div>
        </div>
    </asp:Panel>
</asp:Panel>

<asp:TextBox ID="txtHidden" Visible="false" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="lblCopyright"
    PopupControlID="pnlHead" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" DropShadow="true"
    PopupDragHandleControlID="pnlBody">
</cc1:ModalPopupExtender>

<cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender2" runat="server" TargetControlID="lblCopyright"
    BehaviorID="pnlHeadWD" PopupControlID="pnlHeadWD" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"
    DropShadow="true" PopupDragHandleControlID="pnlBodyWD">
</cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
```

when I tried to call the first `ModalPopupExtender1` then even the second `ModalPopupExtender2` is getting executed and 2 modal popup extenders are shown.

```
public void Populate_Popup(String URL,String Message_Identifier)
{
    this.ModalPopupExtender1.Show();
}

public void Populate_Popup2(string Message)
{
    this.ModalPopupExtender2.Show();
}
```

Comment: If the problem still persist, you need to post complete code

Comment: check example from this website http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Your `TargetControlID="lblCopyright"` is the same for both `ModalPopupExtender`s.

Comment: 1: yes   for both ModalPopupExtender   controls i have the  same    TargetControlID="lblCopyright". 
                            <cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender2" runat="server" TargetControlID="Label1"
                                PopupControlID="pnlHeadWD" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"
                                DropShadow="true" PopupDragHandleControlID="pnlBodyWD">
                            </cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
 code  has  been  changed in this  way
 2: TargetControlID="Label1"  is changed  for the   even then  not  working

Comment: thank's  for  ur  replay  Muhammad Akhtar

now i have   changed the target control id   for  ModalPopupExtender2. but now ia m getting an error telling 
error:
Sys.InvalidOperationException: Two components with the same id 'ctl00_ModalPopupExtender2' can't be added to the application.
i am getting this error 

 thank you